# Akka Java OneForOneStrategy example not compiling

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to paste the OneForOneStrategy into a simple Hello-Akka program, like so based on this documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.2/java/fault-tolerance.html

```
private static SupervisorStrategy strategy = new OneForOneStrategy(10,
        Duration.create("1 minute"),
        new Function<Throwable, SupervisorStrategy.Directive>() {

            @Override
            public SupervisorStrategy.Directive apply(Throwable t) {
                if (t instanceof ArithmeticException) {
                    return resume();
                } else if (t instanceof NullPointerException) {
                    return restart();
                } else if (t instanceof IllegalArgumentException) {
                    return stop();
                } else {
                    return escalate();
                }
            }
        }
);

@Override
public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {
    return strategy;
}
```

However, the resume/restart/stop/escalate method calls don't compile out of the box.
Why not?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: Nevermind, I've resolved!

Answer (score 5):

Just add import listed below:

```
import static akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.escalate;
import static akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.restart;
import static akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.resume;
import static akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.stop;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this issue. You just need to return SupervisorStrategy.resume(), SupervisorStrategy.restart() ... etc.